# Удаление текста из буфера gtk2 c

Tags: c, gui, buffer, gtk2

Передаю текстовое окно `txtwindow` в

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    btn1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("Кнопка");
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(btn1), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(btn_pressed), 
    (gpointer)txtwindow);
    ...
    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(txtwindow));
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

, которое впоследствии окажется вторым аргументом функции `void btn_pressed(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer ptr)`:

```
void btn_pressed(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer ptr){
    clear_txtview(ptr);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(btn2, FALSE);
    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(btn3, FALSE);
    file = popen("ls -la", "r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file))
    {
        gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &iter);
        gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &iter, line, -1);
    }
    int ret;
    ret = pclose(file);
    if(ret!=-1)
    {
        gtk_widget_set_sensitive(btn2, TRUE);
        gtk_widget_set_sensitive(btn3, TRUE);
    }
}`
```

Реализация функции `void clear_txtview(GtkWidget *textView)`:

```
void clear_txtview(GtkWidget *textView){
    GtkTextIter start, end;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textView)); 
    gtk_text_buffer_get_selection_bounds (buffer, &start, &end);
    gtk_text_buffer_delete (buffer, &start, &end);
}
```

При повторном нажатии этой кнопки или другой, текст в текстовом окне не удаляется. Текст добавляется за первым выведенным и доступен для просмотра только в scrolled window, что противоречит требованиям моего технического задания. Помогите, пожалуйста, с реализацией функции удаления.

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде эти итераторы и обозначают границы выделения буфера.  Есть эта функция, но возвращает gtktextmark https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-get-selection-bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gtk_text_buffer_get_selection_bounds()` возвращает итераторы выделенного мышкой куска текста. Собственно он и удаляется. Удалить весь текст можно как-то так:

```
gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buffer, &start);
gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &end);
gtk_text_buffer_delete (buffer, &start, &end);
```

Comment: Fat-Zer, спасибо большое, сообщу результат компиляции

Comment: Fat-Zer, компиляция прошла без ошибок, текст в `txtwindow` удаляется. Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Как ответил @Fat-Zer, решение заключается в раздельном обозначении границ выделения текста в буфере. Функция удаления текста в буфере теперь выглядит следующим образом:

```
void clear_txtview(GtkWidget *textView){
    GtkTextIter start, end;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textView)); 
    gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buffer, &start);
    gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buffer, &end);
    gtk_text_buffer_delete (buffer, &start, &end);
}
```